# Are NULL's necessary when making a MySQL INSERT query?

Tags: php, mysql, null

What I'm asking is whether when inserting a row in a MySQL database the columns that are null need to be included. For instance, when I use phpMyAdmin to insert a row, it will do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO table 
(
`col1`,
`col2`,
`col3`,
`col4`
)
VALUES
(
'value1',
NULL,
NULL,
'value2'
)
```

Assuming the fields are null by default, can I remove columns and NULL values from the insert statement?

Comment: short answer: yes, you can :o)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

by default, when you create column it is nullable (*unless you have set `NOT NULL` on it*). so when you want to insert record for specific columns only, you can omit that column and the values for it are automatically `null`.

```
INSERT INTO table (`col1`  ,`col4`)
           VALUES ('value1','value2')
```

Answer (score 2):

you can remove them.

if there is a default value - you will get that instead.

Answer (score 2):

If the column name is *also* omitted, yes: the *default value*<sup>1</sup> will be assumed.

---

<sup>1</sup> `NULL` is usually - but not always! - the default value for nullable columns. The schema must be consulted to verify this assumption.

Comment: i didn't say your answer is wrong, but it sounds like: "If i pay for that, can i have it?" - "Yes, if you pay for it!" :o)

Comment: @SirRufo Yes, you are correct, I did *over qualify* the response from the question.